# Can the ROC curve of 2 different data sets be same

Tags: roc, skewness

I have been learning about ROC curves and had a doubt that can the ROC of 2 completely different data sets with different skew ( P/(P + N) where `P` and `N` are the actual positives and negative values) be the same?
I am thinking that they cannot be the same since any 2 datasets with different skew will have different TPR and FPR.

Am I right? If I am wrong, can you explain why?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the ROC curve of a dataset? And what is the skew of a dataset?

Comment: the ROC curve you draw by computing the confusion matrix and then calculating the TPR and FPR rate. And the skew is like if one dataset has more positive values and the other has more negative values  and we have to compare the ROC curve of those 2 datasets and they should be same. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: How do you compute the confusion matrix of a dataset? This is not straightfoward. Say I have data x = 1,12,15,87 and y = P,N,P,P what is the confusion matrix for this dataset?

Comment: I should have clarified and suggested an edit, but for my answer I was assuming: ROC of two _models_ built on two different datasets.  And as already mentioned, "data skew" ~ "class imbalance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ROC curves can be the same.

The easiest examples are trivial: a model with perfect separation will consist of the left and top segments, regardless of the data size or balance; and a model with constant probability predictions produced just the diagonal line.

More interesting curves are possible though: it requires the two values of $N$ (resp. $P$) to have nontrivial gcd.  See my answer to [Smallest possible difference between AUC of two ranker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593871/232706) for details, but in brief: the true positive rate and false positive rate have denominators $N$ and $P$, so the allowed points in ROC space lie on the $(N+1)\times(P+1)$ grid.  From there, it follows that their grids coincide on a grid of size $(\operatorname{gcd}(N_1, N_2)+1)\times(\operatorname{gcd}(P_1, P_2)+1)$.  Choosing any set of points on that common grid (in a monotone fashion) yields a valid ROC curve, and from there generating rank-orderings to achieve the necessary TPRs and FPRs doable.

For example, take one dataset with $(N, P) = (9, 5)$ and another with $(N, P) = (6, 10)$.  Here are their available points in ROC space; the first in blue, the second in orange, their overlap getting something like gray because of overlap:

[image: horizontal and vertical dashed lines, in blue and orange, appearing gray where they coincide]

We can pick the points $\{(0,0), (\frac13, \frac35), (\frac23, 1), (1,1)\}$, all on the shared $4\times6$ grid, creating this ROC curve:

[image: an ROC curve connecting stated points]

And working backwards into the two datasets+models:

- model 1 gives three negative and three positive examples prediction 0.75; three negatives and two positives prediction 0.5; and three negatives prediction 0.25.
- model 2 gives two negatives and six positives prediction 0.9; two negatives and four positives prediction 0.5; two negatives prediction 0.1.

You can check that these both produce the above ROC curve.

Comment: Hey, great answer, but I still didn't get the last part of your answer. If N and P are factors of N and P in another dataset, how will the graph be same? Could explain further on this please? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, an example would be great since the wording is a little hard to understand. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry I still dont get it, the language is just too advanced for me, but thanks anyways